# Printing day of the week from date input

Tags: java

in this program it asks the user what date they want to enter in terms of mm/dd/yyyy. It then should print that out and and also what day of the week it would land on. I'm having trouble with the day of the week it would land on. I have it running, but for some reason it is almost a day before for every date a try. I've been looking through the calculations but can't seem to find a reason why it's wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//declare variables and methods
class Main {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  String date, answer = "yes";
  int remainder, month, day, year, days, leapYear;

  public void runProgram()
  {
    while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
    {
      input();
      calculateDays();
      output();

      days = 0;

      System.out.println("\n" + "Do you want to run the program again?");
      answer = scan.nextLine();
    }
  }

  //split date into month, day, year and convert to integers
  public void input()
  {
    System.out.println("\n" + "mm/dd/yyyy:");
    date = scan.nextLine();

    month = Integer.valueOf(date.substring(0, 2));
    day = Integer.valueOf(date.substring(3, 5));
    year = Integer.valueOf(date.substring(6));
    leapYear = Integer.valueOf(date.substring(6, 8));

    System.out.println(leapYear);
    System.out.println(day);
    System.out.println(year);
  }

  //calculate the total amount of days since 01/01/0000
  public void calculateDays()
  {
    days += day;

    //different no. of days pass per month
    switch(month)
    {
      case 1:
        days += 0;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: January/31 days");
        break;
      case 2:
        days += 31;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: February/28 days");
        break;
      case 3:
        days += 59;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: March/31 days");
        break;
      case 4:
        days += 90;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: April/30 days");
        break;
      case 5:
        days += 120;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: May/31 days");
        break;
      case 6:
        days += 151;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: June/30 days");
        break;
      case 7:
        days += 181;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: July/31 days");
        break;
      case 8:
        days += 212;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: August/31 days");
        break;
      case 9:
        days += 243;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: September/30 days");
        break;
      case 10:
        days += 273;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: October/31 days");
        break;
      case 11:
        days += 304;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: November/30 days");
        break;
      case 12:
        days += 334;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: December/31 days");
    }

    days += (year-1)*365;

    days -= leapYear;
    if(leapYear%4 == 0){
      days += (int)(leapYear/4);
    }

    //leap days
    if(year%4 == 0  &&  month <= 2){
      days += (int)((year-1)/4);
    }
    else{
        days += (int)(year/4);
    }
  }

  //calculate and output the day of the week
  public void output()
  {
    remainder = days % 7;
    switch(remainder)
    {
      case 0:
        System.out.println("Day of the week: Saturday");
        break;
      case 1:
        System.out.println("Day of the week: Sunday");
        break;
      case 2:
        System.out.println("Day of the week: Monday");
        break;
      case 3:
        System.out.println("Day of the week: Tuesday");
        break;
      case 4:
        System.out.println("Day of the week: Wednesday");
        break;
      case 5:
        System.out.println("Day of the week: Thursday");
        break;
      case 6:
        System.out.println("Day of the week: Friday");
        break;
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main prog = new Main();
    prog.runProgram();
  }
}
```

Comment: any reason why you don't want to use import java.time.DayOfWeek; in built library ?https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dayofweek-getvalue-method-in-java-with-examples/

Answer (score 0):

comment these lines of code you are already handling for leap year and also initialize days =0 at the begging

```
days -= leapYear;
    if(leapYear%4 == 0){
      days += (int)(leapYear/4);
    }
```

below is the final code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//declare variables and methods
public class Main {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  String date, answer = "yes";
  int remainder, month, day, year, days=0, leapYear;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main prog = new Main();
    prog.runProgram();
  }
  public void runProgram()
  {
    while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
    {
      input();
      calculateDays();
      output();

      days = 0;

      System.out.println("\n" + "Do you want to run the program again?");
      answer = scan.nextLine();
    }
  }

  //split date into month, day, year and convert to integers
  public void input()
  {
    System.out.println("\n" + "mm/dd/yyyy:");
    date = scan.nextLine();

    month = Integer.valueOf(date.substring(0, 2));
    day = Integer.valueOf(date.substring(3, 5));
    year = Integer.valueOf(date.substring(6));
    leapYear = Integer.valueOf(date.substring(6, 8));

    System.out.println(leapYear);
    System.out.println(day);
    System.out.println(year);
  }

  //calculate the total amount of days since 01/01/0000
  public void calculateDays()
  {
    days += day;

    //different no. of days pass per month
    switch(month)
    {
      case 1:
        days += 0;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: January/31 days");
        break;
      case 2:
        days += 31;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: February/28 days");
        break;
      case 3:
        days += 59;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: March/31 days");
        break;
      case 4:
        days += 90;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: April/30 days");
        break;
      case 5:
        days += 120;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: May/31 days");
        break;
      case 6:
        days += 151;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: June/30 days");
        break;
      case 7:
        days += 181;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: July/31 days");
        break;
      case 8:
        days += 212;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: August/31 days");
        break;
      case 9:
        days += 243;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: September/30 days");
        break;
      case 10:
        days += 273;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: October/31 days");
        break;
      case 11:
        days += 304;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: November/30 days");
        break;
      case 12:
        days += 334;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Month: December/31 days");
    }

    days += (year-1)*365;

    if(year%4 == 0  &&  month <= 2){
      days += (int)((year-1)/4);
    }
    else{
        days += (int)(year/4);
    }
  }

  //calculate and output the day of the week
  public void output()
  {
    remainder = days % 7;
    switch(remainder)
    {
      case 0:
        System.out.println("Day of the week: Saturday");
        break;
      case 1:
        System.out.println("Day of the week: Sunday");
        break;
      case 2:
        System.out.println("Day of the week: Monday");
        break;
      case 3:
        System.out.println("Day of the week: Tuesday");
        break;
      case 4:
        System.out.println("Day of the week: Wednesday");
        break;
      case 5:
        System.out.println("Day of the week: Thursday");
        break;
      case 6:
        System.out.println("Day of the week: Friday");
        break;
    }
  }


  
}
```